# Mesosphere inter-service communication using Marathon

Tags: docker, mesos, mesosphere, marathon

I'm currently looking into Mesosphere DCOS to run multiple micro-services using Docker containers. Each micro-services code is already built by my CI into a docker container and uploader to a private container repo.

If I now deploy container A and container B as two different apps using Marathon, how would app A be able to reach app B?
Do I need additional service discovery like Consul?

Would be great if I could have some insights here and maybe even some links / docu to get me started :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current solution would be to use some kind service discovery. 
DCOS already comes with [MesosDNS](https://github.com/mesosphere/mesos-dns) and it will automatically create an DNS entry for each of your containers started by marathon.
See [here](https://docs.mesosphere.com/administration/service-discovery-with-marathon-lb/service-discovery/) for details on using MesosDNS on DCOS.

Hope this helped!

BTW: Feel free to contact the DCOS support directly via the little [chat icon](https://support.mesosphere.com/hc/en-us/articles/206959716) in the DCOS UI.